# Get URL from Firebase Storage (PHP)

Tags: php, firebase

I have URL gs://bucket-name.appspot.com/photos/1F0CB8D1-511E-47F2-AA31-8EC131E38672.jpg,
but I need URL http://.... for show photo on site.

How I can get it? Please, explain in PHP.

Comment: `str_replace('gs', 'http', $theUrl);` See this [useful resource](https://www.php.net/docs.php)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a *signed URL* in Google Cloud Storage, and you can [generate a signed URL in PHP](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/src/get_object_v4_signed_url.php) with:

```
$storage = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
$object = $bucket->object($objectName);
$url = $object->signedUrl(
    # This URL is valid for 15 minutes
    new \DateTime('15 min'),
    [
        'version' => 'v4',
    ]
);

print('Generated GET signed URL:' . PHP_EOL);
print($url . PHP_EOL);
print('You can use this URL with any user agent, for example:' . PHP_EOL);
print('curl ' . $url . PHP_EOL);
```